# snakemake checkpoint and create a expand list/wildcards based on created output files

Tags: snakemake

hope someone can guide me in the right direction. See below for a small working example:

```
from glob import glob

rule all:
    input:
        expand("output/step4/{number}_step4.txt", number=["1","2","3","4"])

checkpoint split_to_fasta:
    input:
        seqfile = "files/seqs.csv"#just an empty file in this example
    output:
        fastas=directory("output/fasta")
    shell:
        #A python script will create below files and I dont know them beforehand.
        "mkdir -p {output.fastas} ; "
        "echo test > {output.fastas}/1_LEFT_sample_name_foo.fa ;"
        "echo test >  {output.fastas}/1_RIGHT_sample_name_foo.fa ;"
        "echo test >  {output.fastas}/2_LEFT_sample_name_spam.fa ;"
        "echo test >  {output.fastas}/2_RIGHT_sample_name_bla.fa ;"
        "echo test >  {output.fastas}/3_LEFT_sample_name_egg.fa ;"
        "echo test >  {output.fastas}/4_RIGHT_sample_name_ham.fa ;"

rule step2:
    input:
        fasta = "output/fasta/{fasta}.fa"
    output:
        step2 = "output/step2/{fasta}_step2.txt",
    shell:
        "cp {input.fasta} {output.step2}"

rule step3:
    input:
        file = rules.step2.output.step2
    output:
        step3 = "output/step3/{fasta}_step3.txt",
    shell:
        "cp {input.file} {output.step3}"

def aggregate_input(wildcards):
    checkpoint_output = checkpoints.split_to_fasta.get(**wildcards).output[0]
    ###dont know where to use this line correctly
    ###files = [Path(x).stem.split("_")[0] for x in glob("output/step3/"+ f"*_step3.txt") ]
    return expand("output/step3/{fasta}_step3.txt", fasta=glob_wildcards(os.path.join(checkpoint_output, "{fasta}.fa")).fasta)

def get_id_files(wildcards):
    blast = glob("output/step3/"+ f"{wildcards.number}*_step3.txt")
    return sorted(blast)

rule step4:
    input:
        step3files = aggregate_input,
        idfiles = get_id_files
    output:
        step4 = "output/step4/{number}_step4.txt",
    run:
        shell("cat {input.idfiles} > {output.step4}")
```

Because of rule all snakemake knows how to "start" the pipeline. I hard coded the numbers 1,2,3 and 4 but in a real situation I dont know these numbers beforehand.

```
expand("output/step4/{number}_step4.txt", number=["1","2","3","4"])
```

What I want is to get those numbers based on the output filenames of split_to_fasta, step2 or step3. And then use it as a target for wildcards. (I can easily get the numbers with glob and split)

I want to do it with wildcards like in `def get_id_files` because I want to execute the next step in parallel. In other words, the following sets of files need to go in the next step:

```
[1_LEFT_sample_name_foo.fa, 1_RIGHT_sample_name_foo.fa]
[2_LEFT_sample_name_spam.fa, 2_RIGHT_sample_name_bla.fa]
[3_LEFT_sample_name_egg.fa]
[4_RIGHT_sample_name_ham.fa]
```

A may need a second checkpoint but not sure how to implement that.

**EDIT (solution):**

I was already worried my question was not so clear so I made another example, see below. This pipeline generates some fake files (end of step 3). From this point I want to continue and process all files with the same id in parallel. The id is the number at the beginning of the filename. I could make a second pipeline that "starts" with step 4 and execute them after each other but that sounds like bad practice. I think I need to define a target for the next rule (step 4) but dont know how to do that based on this situation. The code to define the target itself is something like:

```
    files = [Path(x).stem.split("_")[0] for x in glob("output/step3/"+ f"*_step3.txt") ]
    ids = list(set(files))
    expand("output/step4/{number}_step4.txt", number=ids)
```

The second example (Edited to the solution):

```
from glob import glob

def aggregate_input(wildcards):
    checkpoint_output = checkpoints.split_to_fasta.get(**wildcards).output[0]
    ids = [Path(x).stem.split("_")[0] for x in glob("output/fasta/"+ f"*.fa") ]
    return expand("output/step3/{fasta}_step3.txt", fasta=glob_wildcards(os.path.join(checkpoint_output, "{fasta}.fa")).fasta) + expand("output/step4/{number}_step4.txt", number=ids)

rule all:
    input:
        aggregate_input,

checkpoint split_to_fasta:
    input:
        seqfile = "files/seqs.csv"
    output:
        fastas=directory("output/fasta")
    shell:
        #A python script will create below files and I dont know them beforehand.
        #I could get the numbers if needed
        "mkdir -p {output.fastas} ; "
        "echo test1 > {output.fastas}/1_LEFT_sample_name_foo.fa ;"
        "echo test2 >  {output.fastas}/1_RIGHT_sample_name_foo.fa ;"
        "echo test3 >  {output.fastas}/2_LEFT_sample_name_spam.fa ;"
        "echo test4 >  {output.fastas}/2_RIGHT_sample_name_bla.fa ;"
        "echo test5 >  {output.fastas}/3_LEFT_sample_name_egg.fa ;"
        "echo test6 >  {output.fastas}/4_RIGHT_sample_name_ham.fa ;"

rule step2:
    input:
        fasta = "output/fasta/{fasta}.fa"
    output:
        step2 = "output/step2/{fasta}_step2.txt",
    shell:
        "cp {input.fasta} {output.step2}"

rule step3:
    input:
        file = rules.step2.output.step2
    output:
        step3 = "output/step3/{fasta}_step3.txt",
    shell:
        "cp {input.file} {output.step3}"

def get_id_files(wildcards):
    #blast = glob("output/step3/"+ f"{wildcards.number}*_step3.txt")
    blast = expand(f"output/step3/{wildcards.number}_{{sample}}_step3.txt", sample=glob_wildcards(f"output/fasta/{wildcards.number}_{{sample}}.fa").sample)
    return blast

rule step4:
    input:
        idfiles = get_id_files
    output:
        step4 = "output/step4/{number}_step4.txt",
    run:
        shell("cat {input.idfiles} > {output.step4}")
```

Comment: I don't quite understand what you need, it seems to me your `aggregate_input` function is already enough for checkpoints, could you describe what your need more clearly?

Comment: Uhm it is a bit hard to explain. After step 3 I want to give the pairs as input to a new rule (step 4) where I want to merge the pairs (indicated by the id at beginning of filename). I want to process all pairs in parallel and thus "step 4" can only start when all step 3 is finished. In rule all I hardcoded the "pair" id's for now but this need to be created based on the outputfiles of the previous rules (I think) . I just posted my question here as well https://www.biostars.org/p/9504089/ but slightly different described. (hope I dont violate cross posting rules.)

Comment: I also added a second example.

Comment: What do you mean by "all step 3 is finished"? Does it mean you want all step3 files have been generated before starting step 4 or you want the required step3 output for each id have been generated respectively? If it's the latter one, I think replacing your `blast` line in `get_id_functions` with `blast = expand(f"output/step3/{wildcards.number}_{{sample}}_step3.txt", sample=glob_wildcards(f"output/fasta/{wildcards.number}_{{sample}}.fa").sample)` should work

Comment: I edited the second example with your comment and the tip of SultanOrazbayev on line 5 and 6 and it works now! What would the world look like without you people. I do need to study the code now to understand how it works. Is this what you mean (even though it works)? You can also change your comment to an answer if you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replacing your blast line in get_id_functions in second example with

```
blast = expand(f"output/step3/{wildcards.number}_{{sample}}_step3.txt", sample=glob_wildcards(f"output/fasta/{wildcards.number}_{{sample}}.fa").sample)
```

This is my way of understanding checkpoint, when the input of a rule (say rule `a`) is checkpoint, anything upstream of `a` is blocked by the first evaluation of DAG, after checkpoint has been successfully executed. The second round of evaluation would start with knowing the output of checkpoints.

So in your case, putting checkpoint in rule `all` would hide step2/3/4 at 1st evaluation (since these steps are upstream of `all`). Then checkpoint got executed, then 2nd evaluation. At this time point, you are evaluating a new workflow knowing all outputs of checkpoint, so you can 1. infer the ids 2. infer the corresponding `step3` outputs according to `split_to_fasta` outputs.

1st evaluation: Rule `all` -> checkpoint `split_to_fasta` (TBD)

2nd evaluation(`split_to_fasta` executed): Rule `all` -> checkpoint `split_to_fasta` -> **Rule `step_4`** -> Rule `step_3` -> Rule `step_2`

`get_id_files` happens at `step_4`, where `step_3` has not been executed, this is why you need to infer based on outputs of `split_to_fasta` instead of directly finding the outputs of `step 3`

Comment: thanks again for this. Even though I used the checkpoint wrong here I kinda understand the mechanics. It is mostly lines like your solution I run into. So because step 4 needs the output of step 3, step 3 will be executed first.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the problem correctly, the following line should be changed:

```py
ids = [Path(x).stem.split("_")[0] for x in glob("output/step3/"+ f"*_step3.txt") ]
```

Right now it's `glob`-bing for files in `step3` (I presume these files do not yet exist). Instead, the right thing to `glob` is the output of the `rule split_to_fasta`, so something like this:

```py
ids = [Path(x).stem.split("_")[0] for x in glob("output/fasta*.fa") ]
```

And later to use these `ids` to extract the relevant wildcards and use them in the `expand("output/step3/{fasta}_step3.txt", ...)`.

Sorry this is not a functional example, but the original code is a bit hard to read.

Comment: I do know what you mean and changed the second example. But how can I start step 4 after step 3 is completly finished?

Comment: I see, well the problem is `get_id_files` function doesn't reference any of the checkpoints and `snakemake` will not know that it needs re-evaluation after `step3` is done. So the easiest solution is to turn `step3` into a checkpoint and include a reference to it inside `get_id_files`.

Comment: That is what I was leaning to as well, to re-evaluatie DAG. But I don't know how, can a checkpoint also output files instead of a directory? And how can I use the output of step 2 as input for the checkpoint? (Now trying things) Combining step 2 and 3 is no problem btw if needed but it is a good learning momement like this