Snakemake checkpoint is not evaluated
I have a checkpoint rule that is creating files, and each of those files has to be processed by rule BaseCellCounter. I don't find how to make snakemake understand that bam="SplitBam/{scDNA}/{scDNA}.{clone}.bam", is created  by checkpoint SplitBam, and linking rule AggregateSplitBamOutput doesn't help. As a result the DAG is not built.
all_clones_all_samples = {'Sample_1': ['clone_1'], 'Sample_2': ['clone_1', 'clone_2']}
SAMPLES = ['Sample_1', 'Sample_2']

def get_all_splitbam_file_names(wildcards):
    print('before checkpoint')
    split_dir = checkpoints.SplitBam.get(**wildcards).output["split"]
    print('after checkpoint')
    CLONES = glob_wildcards(f'{split_dir}/{wildcards.scDNA}.{{clone}}.bam').clone
    return expand(f"{split_dir}/{wildcards.scDNA}.{{clone}}.bam",clone=CLONES)

rule all:
    input:
        expand("MergeCounts/{scDNA}.BaseCellCounts.AllCellTypes.tsv", 
        scDNA = SAMPLES),
    default_target: True

checkpoint SplitBam:
    input:
        bam = f"{DATA}/{{scDNA}}_scDNA.bam",
    output:
        split = directory("SplitBam/{scDNA}")
    shell:
        "mkdir -p {output.split} && python create_some_files.py {input.bam}"

rule AggregateSplitBamOutput:
    input:
        bam=get_all_splitbam_file_names,
    output:
        touch("SplitBam/{scDNA}.split_done.txt")

rule BaseCellCounter:
    input:
        txt="SplitBam/{scDNA}.split_done.txt",
        bam="SplitBam/{scDNA}/{scDNA}.{clone}.bam",
    output:
        tsv="BaseCellCounter/{scDNA}/{scDNA}.{clone}.tsv",

def MergeCountsInput(wildcards):
    return expand(f"BaseCellCounter/{{scDNA}}/{{scDNA}}.{clone}.tsv", 
            clone=all_clones_all_samples[wildcards.scDNA])

rule MergeCounts:
    input:
        MergeCountsInput,
    output:
        tsv = "MergeCounts/{scDNA}.BaseCellCounts.AllCellTypes.tsv"


Building DAG of jobs...
before chepoint
MissingInputException in rule BaseCellCounter in file SnakeFile.smk, line 96:
Missing input files for rule BaseCellCounter:
    output: BaseCellCounter/Sample1/Sample_1.Clone_1.tsv,
    wildcards: scDNA=Sample_1, clone=Clone_1
    affected files:
        SplitBam/Sample_1/Sample_1.Clone_1.bam


As you can see in :
def get_all_splitbam_file_names(wildcards):
    print('before checkpoint')
    split_dir = checkpoints.SplitBam.get(**wildcards).output["split"]
    print('after checkpoint')
    CLONES = glob_wildcards(f'{split_dir}/{wildcards.scDNA}.{{clone}}.bam').clone
    return expand(f"{split_dir}/{wildcards.scDNA}.{{clone}}.bam",clone=CLONES)

the print('before checkpoint') statement gets printed but not the print('after checkpoint'). Do  I use checkpoints incorrectly?

I indeed used checkpoints incorrectly. The logic was flawed, I aggregated too early, you should only aggregate when the wildcard first appears in snakemake's logic. The following logic worked:
SAMPLES = ['Sample_1', 'Sample_2']

def aggregate(wildcards):
    split_dir = checkpoints.SplitBam_scDNAValid.get(**wildcards).output["split"]
    CLONES = glob_wildcards(f'{split_dir}/{wildcards.scDNA}.{{clone}}.bam').clone
    return expand(
        f"BaseCellCounter/{wildcards.scDNA}/{wildcards.scDNA}.{{clone}}.tsv",
        clone=CLONES)

rule all:
    input:
        expand("MergeCounts/{scDNA}.BaseCellCounts.AllCellTypes.tsv", 
        scDNA = SAMPLES),
    default_target: True

checkpoint SplitBam:
    input:
        bam = f"{DATA}/{{scDNA}}_scDNA.bam",
    output:
        split = directory("SplitBam/{scDNA}")
    shell:
        "mkdir -p {output.split} && python create_some_files.py {input.bam}"

rule BaseCellCounter:
    input:
        bam="SplitBam/{scDNA}/{scDNA}.{clone}.bam",
    output:
        tsv="BaseCellCounter/{scDNA}/{scDNA}.{clone}.tsv",

rule MergeCounts:
    input:
        aggregate
    output:
        tsv = "MergeCounts/{scDNA}.BaseCellCounts.AllCellTypes.tsv"

Also, this way I don't even need all_clones_all_samples as I don't need to know in advance which clones are present.

The more I look at this Snakefile, the less I understand how it is supposed to be working. You have this line:
expand(f"BaseCellCounter/{{scDNA}}/{{scDNA}}.{{clone}}.tsv", scDNA = SMPL)

You have an f-String here but all the curly braces are doubled, so this just reduces to the more readable:
expand("BaseCellCounter/{scDNA}/{scDNA}.{clone}.tsv", scDNA = SMPL)

And when I run it I get the error: "No values given for wildcard 'clone'." Which makes perfect sense as there is indeed no 'clone' argument passed to the expand function. This error occurs before the message "Building DAG of jobs". So I actually don't see how you possibly got the output you state from this exact Snakefile.
I do have a couple of general suggestions:

When trying to debug the whole checkpoint thing, use this as a placeholder rule:

checkpoint SplitBam:                                                                                
    input:                                                                                          
        bam = f"{DATA}/{{scDNA}}_scDNA.bam",                                                        
    output:                                                                                         
        split = directory(f"SplitBam/{{scDNA}}")                                                    
    shell:                                                                                          
        """mkdir -p {output.split}                                                                  
           cd {output.split}                                                                        
           awk '{{print >$0}}' <{input.bam}                                                         
        """  

That awk command just just takes a text file with a filename on each line as input and creates those files, so you can do something like this to make a dummy input for testing:
$ printf 'split%s.bam\n' 1 2 3   > DATA/SMPL1_scDNA.bam

This will allow someone (like me) to test your logic without needing your create_some_files.py or any real BAM files.

The thing with checkpoints in Snakemake is that all they really do is allow you to combine two workflows into one, with a DAG re-build in the middle. So my advice would be to get everything working in two separate workflows, and only then try to combine them with a checkpoint. If you can post a working example which runs in two separate stages then I should be able to show how to combine them into one workflow with an appropriate checkpoint.


Thank you so much! And I apologize, this was an horribly formulated question with the code not leading to the error. I tried to simplify the original code and messed up (both with f-strings and the code).
I edited the code to correspond to the error. Your comment + https://stackoverflow.com/q/70543163/18324236 helped me understand the flaws in the logic. I answered with the correct logic.
Regarding point 1., I'll try to do better, I didnt expect people to run it, so thanks for taking the time!

No need to apologize! Reducing complex code like this to self-contained test cases is really tricky. Writing tidy Snakemake code is also hard. I'm delighted you got it working. If you feel that my answers are what helped you then I'd appreciate it if you could accept my answer (so I get StackOverflow kudos). Thanks!

I have already accepted mine in case somebody stumbles upon this post. I can't even upvote you as I don't have enough reputation haha sorry

Oh well, never mind.
